# Android- dynamically get text from user and add it to table layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am kind of new to Android developing and I came across some problem.
I am building an app where I want to pop a dialog for the user, get the text from the dialog and add it dynamically as a cell in a predefined table layout. This I want to do multiple times, with each click on a button.

I apologize if this is a duplication, but I searched many solutions online and couldn't get any of them working for me.
I think my main issue is the asynchronous of the AlertDialog.Builder and my code doesn't wait for it as I can't block UI threads. So I tried to set a listener but that doesn't seems to work either.

Any help, or some fundamental knowledge about listeners in Android will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Instance variable defined in the class:

```
String userInput;
```

The method for showing the dialog:

```
 public void showDialog(String message, final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertBox.setMessage(message);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alertBox.setView(input);
    alertBox.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    userInput = input.getText().toString();
                }
            });
    alertBox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        }
    });
    alertBox.show();
}
```

The call for the dialog and setting a new row, called by a button click:

```
    public void addTeam(View view) {
    showDialog("Please enter text", this);
    //Here I want to already have userInput var, thus it should be after the click.

    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    name.setText(userInput);
    name.setTextSize(20);
    name.setPaintFlags(name.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    row.addView(name);
    //teamsTable is a TableLayout defined int the XML
    teamsTable.addView(row, ++nTeamTableRowCount);
}
```

Comment: Everything happens on the ui thread. So where is the blocking ui thread come from?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My approach is setting a dialog from the activity and use the text input. Is that wrong?

Comment: unless you have a thread (background) thread all operations are on the ui thread. You only create a thread when you want off load work to a backgroudn thread. So where is the bloacking ui thread in your post come from

Comment: I didn't create any blocking thread, is there a default UI thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a method in your `Activity` that update the `TableLayout`

```
private void addRow(String userInput) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    name.setText(userInput);
    name.setTextSize(20);
    name.setPaintFlags(name.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    row.addView(name);
    teamsTable.addView(row, ++nTeamTableRowCount);
}
```

and call it in `onClick()`:

```
alertBox.setPositiveButton("OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            addRow(userInput);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface, call it e.g. Action

```
public interface Action {

    public void onCompleted(String input);

}
```

Change your methods signature

```
public void showDialog(String message, final Context context, final Action action)
```

Change your positive button onClick method.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    userInput = input.getText().toString();        
    if(action!=null) action.onCompleted(userInput);
}
```

Then e.g. create an anonymous class

```
 showDialog("Please enter text", this, new Action() {

      public void onCompleted(String input) {

          //Do what you want with input here. e.g.

          TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
          TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          row.setLayoutParams(lp);
          TextView name = new TextView(this);
          name.setText(userInput);
          name.setTextSize(20);
          name.setPaintFlags(name.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
          row.addView(name);
          //teamsTable is a TableLayout defined int the XML
          teamsTable.addView(row, ++nTeamTableRowCount);

      }

 });
```

You could clean it up a bit by creating a dedicated class for your dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! although @brescia123 solved it for me, may I please know what is the 'Action' class? where does the action returns from, and what happens if it is null? Is that means the click get lost?

Comment: You should read on interfaces and loose coupling. Then you will recognize brescia123 answer isn't the best. With interfaces you add another layer of abstraction. With brescia123 answer, your button is coupled to your activity and will always do the same, with my answer you can control what it does by creating different actions and you could use your dialog even in other activities.